# Group by based on data relation between records

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, grouping, having

This is my Table:

```
ID | startTime  | endTime 
0  | 1380209017 | 1380470025
1  | 1390480010 | 1390480018
2  | 1390480218 | 1390480888 
3  | 1390480999 | 1390490888
```

Right now I do following to get the number of records per day

```
SELECT 
count(date(tripStartTime,'unixepoch')) AS count,
date(tripStartTime,'unixepoch') AS date 
FROM TripsCalculated  
GROUP BY date(tripStartTime,'unixepoch')
```

Which results in something like this:

```
count | date 
1  | 2013-09-29
3  | 2014-01-23
```

Now I need to get the number of records per day, BUT records that are <5 min apart should count as one to get

```
count | date 
1  | 2013-09-29
1  | 2014-01-23
```

Can I achieve that using SQLite? How? My platform is android by the way.

Comment: Is the *id* column sequential without gaps? Then you can do a self join *on t2.id = t1.id + 1* to get access to the previous row.

Comment: @dnoeth Yes, but gaps can happen occasional. However, it is not a problem, if merging failes because of a gap. It can be n previous rows.

Comment: Well, cursor is good for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about gaps you can easily access the previous row using a self-join.

```
SELECT 
   COUNT(*) AS COUNT,
   tripStartTime AS DATE 
FROM 
 (
   SELECT DATE(tripStartTime,'unixepoch') AS tripStartTime
   FROM TripsCalculated AS t1 LEFT JOIN TripsCalculated AS t2
   ON t2.id = t1.id+1
   WHERE t2.tripStartTime - t1.tripEndTime > 5*60 
 )
GROUP BY DATE(tripStartTime,'unixepoch')
```

Check the logic of the WHERE-condition, it's untested and i don't like self-joins as every column exists twice :-)

Comment: The requirement is to group n trips not just 2 with break of <5 min in between. I removed the missleading part of my question now.

Comment: The query will filter **all** rows where there's less than 5 minutes between 2 rows. But it will fail if there are no rows > 5 min within a day -> no result for that day. Without "Windowed Aggregate Functions" (e.g. ROW_NUMBER) this kind of query is really hard. How many rows do you need to process?

Comment: Around 1000 to 130000 rows. However I could make a query for a certain time frame, if the calculation gets too heavy. So that maximum 10000 rows are processed.

Comment: If you need exact answer you need to go with a cursor as PerterRing suggested. The logic is easy, sort the data by startTime and then for each row: compare current StartTime with previous row's EndTime, if the difference is greater than 5 minutes increase a counter by 1. When the data changes emit a row and start a new count. I'm not going to write that, i didn't write cursors like that for at least 10 years :-)